# Fill table with values in ranges from another table

Tags: c

I have an one-dimensional table with degrees:

double tabledegrees[10]={0.2,3.4,4.3,1.2,4.6,4.5,3.8,1.5,3.4,3.7};

The degrees are always in the interval [0,5].

I want to count the number of thermometers whose degree belong in each of the intervals [0,1), [1,2),[2,3), [3,4),[4,5] and store these values in an array of integers of size 5, in which cell 0 belongs to degrees belonging to the interval [0,1), cell 1 to degrees belonging to the interval [1,2), and so on.

I want to use floor function and not a sequence of if commands.

The following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

  
double tabledegrees[10]={0.2,3.4,4.3,1.2,5.6,4.5,3.8,1.5,3.4,3.7};
double tabledegreesfloored[10];

for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
    tabledegreesfloored[i] = floor(tabledegrees[i]);
   }


for (int j=0;j<10;j++){
    printf("%.f \n", tabledegreesfloored[j]);
   }
}
```

returns:

> 0  3  4  1  5  4  3  1  3  3

How to achive this?

Comment: Floor, convert to integer, and you have your index?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you wrote?

Comment: @AllanWind I wanto to use another table of size 5 to store the values of a table with size 10. for example the another table for this example shoud be [1,2,3,2,1]

Comment: You have no temperatures in the interval 2 so I think your example data is wrong (unless I miss something).  See answer below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an array of thermometers and use the interval to index into the array as you count them:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(a) sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a)

int main() {
    double tabledegrees[10]={0.2,3.4,4.3,1.2,5.6,4.5,3.8,1.5,3.4,3.7};
    size_t thermometers[5] = {0};
    for (size_t i=0; i < LEN(tabledegrees); i++) {
        if(tabledegrees[i] < 0 || tabledegrees[i] >= LEN(thermometers)) {
            printf("skip data out of range %lf\n", tabledegrees[i]);
            continue;
        }
        thermometers[(int) floor(tabledegrees[i])]++;
    }
    for (size_t i=0; i < LEN(thermometers); i++)
        printf("%zu: %zu\n", i, thermometers[i]);
}
```

and here is example output:

```
skip data out of range 5.600000
0: 1
1: 2
2: 0
3: 4
4: 2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to do this without pointers?

Comment: Which pointers and why are you concerned about those?

Comment: I am reffering to *tabledegrees

Comment: I tweaked the answer to use a macro.  You can hard-coded the array lengths but this would be a better way to do it.

Comment: If your assumptions don't hold (i.e. values are outside the range you said it would be), this is going to break badly.  If it's one-off that's fine but if you use this in production writhe a function that extract the min and max to ensure it's in the expected range, otherwise abort with an error message.  It's a too much code to write, but  another option would be to use a hash table to map thermometer to count.  That way you no longer a small range, say, you have two values -1e6 to 1e6 would require a 2e6 * sizeof(size_t) = 8 MB array but only 2 value in a hash table.

Comment: Updated answer with a minimal check and it rejects a value out of range.  You fix that by removing the value or bumping the thermometer array to size 6 in this case.